# how can I get the value of x

Tags: trigonometry

I've trying to get the `x` value of the :

sin(x+90) / sin(x+210) = 0.2222

is there a way to solve this equation, not numerically !

Comment: Are the numbers in degrees or radians? And is that 0.2222 exactly or 2/9?

Comment: Try the cofunction identities.

Comment: the numbers are in degrees @Burr I've tried but didn't get it

Comment: what did you do so far?

Answer (score 1):

$\sin (x+90^{\circ}) = \cos x, \sin (x+210^{\circ}) = \sin (x+30^{\circ}+180^{\circ}) = -\sin (x+30^{\circ}) = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin x - \frac{1}{2}\cos x$. Then try to write the equation in the form: $\alpha \sin x = \beta \cos x \to \tan x = \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha} \to x = \tan^{-1}(\frac{\beta}{\alpha})$.

Comment: @BRICK-fan my problem is whith the part you didn'T explain, meaning  how to get the a sin(x) = B cos(x)